# Espresso, scroll to bottom of dynamical loading ListView

Tags: android, android-espresso

normaly scrolling down within a Testcase I could use this peace of code:

```
 onView( withId( R.id.button)).perform( scrollTo(), click());
```

However in this test i want to scroll down a Listview, where the childelements are loaded dynamically (I dont know how many there are), when the view is scrolled down. Is there anything like scroll to bottom in espresso like in Robotium?

My workarround:

```
int [] childCount =  getListElements();
    for(int i = 0;i<childCount[0];i++) {
        onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.ScheduleOrderListViewListView)).atPosition(i).perform(click());
        childCount =  getListElements();
    }
```

with

```
public int[] getListElements(){
    final int[] counts = new int[1];
    onView(withId(R.id.ScheduleOrderListViewListView)).check(matches(new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) view;

            counts[0] = listView.getCount();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {

        }
    }));
    return counts;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onData()` to interact with ListView elements. If you want to scroll to the bottom, just scroll to the last item. For example:

```
onData(instanceOf(ListData.class))
        .atPosition(INITIAL_LIST_SIZE - 1)
        .perform(scrollTo());
```

Comment: i dont know the list size during loading - did something quick and dirty workarround... ill put the code above